# How do I preprocess_html() a panelized page?

Tags: theming, panels

My intentions is to take a panelized page and use fields provided in that page to create class names on the body element.

When I preprocess the page, I don't get the original node information and can't pull the information I need.

My panelized page has 1 pane that has the node-> content pane in there.

If I could just get the NID of the current page, then it would be okay. But that doesn't even show up in the variables in the theme_preprocess_html() when a page has been panelized.

Comment: Nevermind, The solution that I needed was just to use arg() to get my node id and then I was able to use node_load() to get/check values I wanted to use for the classes_array to add to the body.

Comment: You could also use `$node = menu_get_object('node');` to retrieve the loaded node from the menu router cache.

Comment: David, menu_get_object() was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Solution was to use [menu_get_object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)(). [Here is a nice article outline usages of it as well.](http://drupalsun.com/node/32677)

```
$node = menu_get_object('node');
```

Thanks you [David](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7153/david-thomas) for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the nid is in the URL, you can use the [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function to get it.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Works good enough for now, i'd still like to find a way to make it happen within the preprocess system either with a custom module or in template.php somehow. Just a common technique I find my self doing.

Comment: Well, you can call `arg()` from within `YOURTHEME_preprocess_html`. Also, the HTML template is really clueless about its contents, as the pieces are rendered before its containers. Maybe you should take a look at `hook_page_alter`.